# Intuitive explanation of difference in $r$-dependence between dipole and monopole

Tags: electrostatics, potential, dipole, multipole-expansion

For an electric monopole, its potential scales with $\frac{1}{r}$, where $r$ is the distance from the point of interest to the charge. However, for a dipole, its potential scales with $\frac{1}{r^2}$.

I understand how the latter is derived. But is there an intuitive explanation on why the dipole potential ends up having a second order dependence or $r$?

Comment: And it doesn't stop there... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multipole_expansion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way to think about it (though it isn't mathematically rigorous).

From very far away the dipole would appear to have zero charge and thus there wouldn't be an electric field at all.  However, you also know that the electric field falls off as $1/r$, so from very far away you'd expect the electric field to be small.  The additional charge cancellation affect in a dipole accounts for the field falling off faster, and thus a $1/r^2$ potential.

Comment: The part about from far away, the net charge is 0 pulled it together for me. Don't why I forgot about that part. Thanks!

Comment: @Asy Expand $|\vec{r}+\vec{\delta}/2|^{-1} - |\vec{r}-\vec{\delta}/2|^{-1}|$ as a Taylor series (Binomial) about $\delta = 0$ and you'll see in symbols what mcFreid has put into words.